# VBA script that maps https to \\ paths for downloads

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a script to download files using VBA. The VBA script has to download items that start with https://collaboration.company.corp/collrooms/specificfolder or with \collaboration.company.corp@SSL\DavWWWRoot\collrooms\specificfolder
The specific folders are the same.

If I allow the script to select the specific mapping, it will only recognize it if I use the definition \collaboration.company.corp@SSL\DavWWWRoot\collrooms\specificfolder

How can I create a mapping in VBA to tell Excel that https://collaboration.company.corp/collrooms/specificfolder and \collaboration.company.corp@SSL\DavWWWRoot\collrooms\specificfolder is the same and that the first specification is also valid?

My code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FolderSelection()

    'Shows the folder picker dialog in order the user to select the folder
    'in which the downloaded files will be saved.

    Dim FoldersPath     As String

    'Show the folder picker dialog.
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a folder to save your files..."
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Sheets("Main").Range("B4") = "-"
            MsgBox "You did't select a folder!", vbExclamation, "Canceled"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            FoldersPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    'Pass the folder's path to the cell. HERE I AM MISSING THE MAPPING. It will show files starting with https if selected and not transfer it to the other structure.
    Sheets("Main").Range("B4") = FoldersPath

End Sub

Sub Clear()

    'Clears the URLs, the result column and the folder's path.

    Dim LastRow     As Long

    'Find the last row.
     With Sheets("Main")
        .Activate
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Clear the ranges.
    If LastRow > 7 Then
        With Sheets("Main")
            .Range("C8:D" & LastRow).ClearContents
            .Range("B4:D4").ClearContents
            .Range("B4").Select
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

and the other part of the download macro is

```
'Check if the folder exists. I did not check whether it will also download with the https structure?
DownloadFolder = sh.Range("B4")
On Error Resume Next
If Dir(DownloadFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "The path is incorrect!", vbCritical, "Folder's Path Error"
    sh.Range("B4").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

I tried with a script that I found on Stackoverflow but it does not work

I created an additional module:

```
    Sub test()
      Dim dm As New DriveMapper
      Dim sharepointFolder As Scripting.Folder

      Set sharepointFolder = dm.MapDrive("https://collaboration.company.corp/collrooms/")
' unsure whether I have to add something here and whether this will work with https

      Debug.Print sharepointFolder.Path
    End Sub
```

and added the following WebDAV mapping as a new CLASS

```
Option Explicit

Private oMappedDrive As Scripting.Drive
Private oFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Private oNetwork As New WshNetwork

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
  UnmapDrive
End Sub

Public Function MapDrive(NetworkPath As String) As Scripting.Folder
  Dim DriveLetter As String, i As Integer

  UnmapDrive

  For i = Asc("Z") To Asc("A") Step -1
    DriveLetter = Chr(i)
    If Not oFSO.DriveExists(DriveLetter) Then
      oNetwork.MapNetworkDrive DriveLetter & ":", NetworkPath
      Set oMappedDrive = oFSO.GetDrive(DriveLetter)
      Set MapDrive = oMappedDrive.RootFolder
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function

Private Sub UnmapDrive()
  If Not oMappedDrive Is Nothing Then
    If oMappedDrive.IsReady Then
      oNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive oMappedDrive.DriveLetter & ":"
    End If
    Set oMappedDrive = Nothing
  End If
End Sub
```

The question is also whether removing the  dispose method "Class_Terminate" which unmaps the drive would help? When the class goes out of scope then the drive get's unmapped. And how I could put it all together.